# Using Geocoder backend in AVD emulator

Tags: android, geocoding, google-maps-android-api-2, android-virtual-device

I am using Google Maps Android APIv2, which required me to create an AVD using the Android 4.2.1 lib without Play services and install vending.apk and gms manually through adb. This works great for loading Maps in the AVD; however, I am unable to use the Geocoder service, which I assume is because I don't have the full Google Play Services lib to provide it. I've tried installing com.android.location, through NetworkLocation.apk which did not work. 
The Geocoder does work fine on the actual device which has all the Google Play packages.

I'm trying to figure out how to manually put in the Geocoder backend to work with my Android 4.2.1 AVD. Anyone able to help?